# Getting SHA1 checksum of multiple files Python

Tags: python-2.7, sha1

I am trying to get SHA1 checksum of multiple files.

I tried solution form this thread [Generating one MD5/SHA1 checksum of multiple files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807537/generating-one-md5-sha1-checksum-of-multiple-files-in-python)

So I put together following:

```
    MainScene = "C:/MainScene.xml"
    MainScreen = "C:/MainScreen.xml"
    Main = "C:/main.brs"
    Manifest = "C:/manifest"
    flist= [MainScene,MainScreen,Main,Manifest]
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha1(open(flist[0], 'rb').read())
    for fname in flist[1:]:
        hash_obj.update(open(fname, 'rb').read())
    checksum = hash_obj.digest()
    print checksum
```

But output would be:

But it gives me wrong results:

> '\xdcRjgd\xcb"1\xadZ\x88\xf2\xb6\x18\xd7i)\x19\xc7)'

Which is not correct, I think that issue is with my files list, can someone please tell me what is wrong about it?

Comment: Why is that the wrong result - what are you expecting? Do you mean to use `.hexdigest()` for instance?

Comment: Sorry if dumb question, as i am pretty new to this, but i expect something like this: "a5ed2fab88bd0f714f417b55b690c2bc8c1d8d9e"

Comment: use `.hexdigest()` instead of `.digest()` ?

Comment: Thank you, this simple change did the trick!